# Plot a data set neatly in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm programming in MATLAB. I've got a data set which is reduced in dimensions and I want to plot a it like the figure below:

[image]

This image is produced by python but I think there must be a way to plot it in MATLAB.

Is there a switch for plot or plot3 to make each point a shape like the image above?

I'll be thankful for your answers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this close to what you need?

```
x = rand(1,1000);
y = rand(1,1000);
j = jet(1000);
scatter(x,y,10,j(ceil(x*1000),:),'filled','MarkerEdgeColor','k')
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly the thing I need... Thank you Mr Roberts :)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify [lineseries properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lineseriesproperties.html) to get the look you want. Example:

```
figure
plot(rand(1,1e3), rand(1,1e3), 'o', ...
    'MarkerFaceColor', 'g', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k')
```

[image: Example plot]

Answer (score 0):

The usual way would be to make a 3d scatterplot. It will plot your points as flat markers. If you want spheres, you can write a small script to do that. Check http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/sphere.html